# find File on Hard drive and set file path as a variable

Tags: file, variables, set, find

I want to find a specific executable file on a computer using a batch file and set the path of that executable file as a variable in my batch file i found a search command using dir /s /p filename.
it displays the path of the file but i cant set it as a variable.

Volume in drive C is OS
 Volume Serial Number is 5C11-338D

Directory of C:\Program Files\McAfee\Agent

08/28/2019  08:24 AM           173,856 cmdagent.exe
               1 File(s)        173,856 byte

How do i set the directory path as a variable.